# Updating scope with an attribute that is being changed manually

Tags: angularjs

I've been thinking for hours about this problem and haven't been able to figure out how to do it in an elegant way.
I'm implementing a simple video player where I let the user trim the video (meaning, choose a start and end time). I get a dynamic array of videos from the server, looks something like this:

```
$scope.videos = 
    [{
        id: "1",
        start: 122,
        end: 187,
        length: 352,
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ePGMfDkTHo"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        start: 122,
        end: 187,
        length: 352,
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVlM2LW90nU"
    }... etc];
```

And with ng-repeat I display the videos on the client.

This is what I have in my view for each iframe that hold a video:

```
<iframe class="video" length="{{asset.length}}" start="{{asset.start}}" end="{{asset.end}}" original-url="{{ asset.url }}" data-value-start="asset.start"></iframe>
```

(where asset represent a video in the array)

I have a play bar where I let the user change the start and end time of the videos. Once the user changes the start and end time from the view I change the custom attributes accordingly in the iframe tag:

```
$scope.$apply(function()
   {
      $caller.attr('src',$scope.trustSrc(createEmbedUrl(url, $scope.newAssetData.start, $scope.newAssetData.end)));
      $caller.attr('start', $scope.newAssetData.start);
   });
```

My problem is, that once the user is done changing the times, I need to send back to the server the new start and end time. I was expecting that changing 'start' and 'end' attribute would change the same attributes in the video scope variable but it doesn't happen. I was thinking od "dirty" ways to solve this problem without Angular (such as adding another custom attribute in the view of 'vidId' and have it be my guide to track the new start and end times but it just seems wrong to do it.

What am I missing?

Thank you,
Mila

Comment: you may need to run digest cycle manually

Comment: I used $scope.$apply and this didn't help unfortunately
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $caller.attr('src',$scope.trustSrc(createEmbedUrl(url, $scope.newAssetData.start, $scope.newAssetData.end)));
    $caller.attr('start', $scope.newAssetData.start);
   });

Comment: if you are using it inside directive then do try `$scope.$evalAsync(function(){ //you code here});` or if it is inside controller I'd prefer to use `$timeout` then code would be `$timeout(function(){
 //your code here
})`

Comment: Can you provide us with the whole piece of code – controller, its template and iframe's directive?